Как автоматически привязать к новой задаче сотрудников подразделения по API? Bitrix24
Как автоматически привязать к новой задаче сотрудников подразделения по API? Как реализовать привязку сотрудников подразделения к новой задаче?
Хотим реализовать автоматическое создание задач в Bitrix24 по API, но не имеются трудности с тем, как заполнить поля  (RESPONSIBLE_ID и ACCOMPLICES). Каждая задача должна формоваться для определённого департамента и в поле RESPONSIBLE_ID должен содержать руководителя подразделения, а ACCOMPLICES должен содержать всех подчиненных руководителя департамента. Все задача попадают в специальную группу, где множество департаментов.
Может кто-то сталкивался?
